# JDBI generic CrudDao interface with dynamic table names

Tags: java, jpa, spring-data-jpa, jdbi

I have a parent JDBI interface that my daos inherit from (as seen in [JDBI's docs](https://jdbi.org/#_annotations_and_inheritance)):

```
@UseClasspathSqlLocator
public interface CrudDao<T, ID> {
  @SqlUpdate 
  void insert(@BindBean T entity);

  @SqlQuery 
  Optional<T> findById(ID id);

  @SqlQuery
  List<T> list();

  @SqlUpdate
  void update(@BindBean T entity);

  @SqlUpdate
  void deleteById(ID id);
}
```

The technique above requires me to create insert.sql, update.sql, deleteById.sql, list.sql, and findById.sql, for each DAO that I create. Since these latter three sql statements would be identical among all the DAO classes (except for the table name), is it possible to specify the sql statement only once and have all the inheriting CrudDao classes use them?

I'm reminded of how Spring JPA's [SpEL supports](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query.spel-expressions) the `#{#entityName}` syntax for queries.

Comment: Were you able to figure this out? Trying something similar

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is something that could help you.

Check out the @define annotation.

[How to dynamically bind a table name in JDBI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23622183/how-to-dynamically-bind-a-table-name-in-jdbi)